# Ability to remove the bounty and get reputation back

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

By mistake I started a bounty and lost 200 reputation points leaving me with only 215.

Is there a way to remove this bounty function from your own question?

Bounties in play:

- [Play wav file backward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267488/play-wav-file-backward)
- [Netbeans debugger works faster than normal run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398892/java-netbeans-debugging-session-works-faster-than-normal-run)

Comment: What, no bounty on this question?

Comment: I was going to make another thread about this but them saw yours! I would up vote you but my rep is sooo damn low! If you set a bounty for a question, and nobody answers the question to receive a bounty, then you should be able to get your rep points back OR get some of them back.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No. Bounty grants are irrevocable.

That's why there's a JavaScript confirmation dialog, informing you of the permanence of the bounty, when you initiate the action.

Comment: It seems like it would be fair if one went through the trouble of figuring it out on their own that they should be able to award the bounty back to themselves - perhaps under the vote of others to prevent people trying to circumvent the policy.

Comment: Then at the very least it should be possible to award the bounty to an answer you've created yourself. I recently placed a bounty on a question that nobody was able to provide an answer for. Within a few minutes of placing the bounty, I finally found the solution myself (after days of searching), but there was no way for me to remove the bounty. There is now 23 hours left to award the bounty, and the only other "answer" on the question does not deserve it.

Comment: My question wasn't answered, why should I loose my reputation points?

Answer (score 10):

I somewhat doubt that it could be removed, since that'd allow the potential to "game the system" by starting bounties, getting people to reply, and then removing them.

I wouldn't worry too much about reputation - it's fairly easy to acquire over time if you're active on the site, and if you're not active, then it doesn't really matter anyways.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think the system needs changing, in fairness I suppose it could be possible set up a new feature to allow bounties to be removed as long as it was within, say 60 seconds, and no answers had been received.  Maybe even if no views had been registered, to be super-strict.

But, as Jeff points out, there is a confirmation, and the permanence is quite explicit, so I don't think there's much added value with such a hypothetical feature request.

Comment: There's a confirmation when you initiate the bounty, and another when you accept an answer, that both make it clear that the actions can't be undone. I don't think we should cater to people that can't be bothered to read the warnings.

Comment: What if my bounties going to be rewarded to the answer not deserving.