# Bounty not awarded even though question answered

Tags: support, bounties

According to [Meta StackOverflow question 21529](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21529/ability-to-remove-the-bounty-and-get-reputation-back), I know that it is not possible to remove a bounty once it's been started.

I answered [StackOverflow question 3251056](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251056/plotting-gps-info-with-ruby/3681690#3681690), on Thursday, September 9th, when the question stated it had a bounty that would end in 12 hours. Now I'm not seeing anything about the bounty, and according to the [revisions history on my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3681690/revisions), I answered the question yesterday, Friday, September 10th.

- What happened to the bounty?
- Why does the revision history show the wrong date for when I answered the question?

Comment: I am in a similar situation that a bounty of 250 rep was not awarded. In my case I answered and the answer was accepted as the correct answer several days before the bounty expired, the answer had 3 up-votes and was the only answer. The [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28509594/451475).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, there were no eligible answers at the time that the bounty ended. Bounty auto-acceptance rules state that only answers with a total score of at least 2 are eligible for auto-acceptance. Perhaps you didn't recieve the second upvote until after the bounty ended?

As for the time zone problem, that is easily explained. I see from your profile that you are located in Missouri, which is GMT-5, so you answered around 8 PM local time on the 9th, which was 1 AM on September 10 GMT.

Answer (score -1):

For the post date part, you posted at a little after 1am on the 10th; is it possible you posted late on the 9th and live in a western time zone? (Times on SO are in UTC)

As for the missing bounty, as far as I know the only way the bounty could've gone completely unrewarded is if a mod removed it, but I don't know why they would have -- I can't see the logs to know for sure

Comment: What happens if at the time of expiry no answer meets the criteria for auto awarding? Edit: [Looks like that could explain it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067)

Comment: @Martin Ah, yes; I thought it always rewarded it, but apparently not