# Can I remove bounty from my question?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ability to remove the bounty and get reputation back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21529/ability-to-remove-the-bounty-and-get-reputation-back)

Is it possible to remove bounty that I have started on my own question? I think I am no more interested in getting answer to that question.
Removing question won't help as I want to keep reputation that I have got on it.

It has completed 7 days. Now it is saying that I have to wait for another 23 hours.

Fine. understood that bounty system is to get attention. But mine is exceptional situation. I didn't got attention, no answer, no comments. Why would I loose rep for that. Isn't that a flaw in bounty system.

Answer (score 4):

It would be against the bounty concept if you would be able to offer bounty, wait for answers, and then remove the cheese from their nose just before it ends. And it would be unfair too. So you should simply think twice before starting a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not way you can remove/revoke the bounty once you offer it.

Comment: I haven't offered it yet.

Comment: You offer it once you set it (the rep points are subtracted directly).